# How to remove undefined from a list of items?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, find, undefined

How to prevent appearing `undefined` in the output?

```
var item1 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(2) a').html(),
    item2 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(3) a').html(),
    item3 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(4) a').html(),
    item4 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(5) a').html();

$('div').html(item1+item2+item3+item4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put them all in an array and then filter it.

```js
const array = [item1, item2, item3, item4];
const onlyDefined = array.filter(item => item !== undefined);
```

If you're not doing anything else with the variables, you could also do it all in chunk, by looping over the numbers 2 through 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item1 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(2) a').html(),
item2 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(3) a').html(),
item3 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(4) a').html(),
item4 = $(result).find('.item:nth-child(5) a').html();

item1 = typeof item1 === 'undefined' ? '' : item1;
item2 = typeof item2 === 'undefined' ? '' : item2;
item3 = typeof item3 === 'undefined' ? '' : item3;
item4 = typeof item4 === 'undefined' ? '' : item4;

$('div').html(item1+item2+item3+item4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to set a **default value** to prevent `undefined` values in your code:

```js
const item = undefined ?? "";
//output: ""
```

or You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them:

```js
const items = [undefined, "Hello", undefined, " World!"];
const filtereditems = items.filter(x=>x); 

const joindItems= filtereditems.join(""); 
//output: 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and cleanest way )

```
array.filter(Boolean)
```